# Placeholder in ssh config in HostName

Tags: ssh-config

I am trying to simplify the following part:

```
Host sandbox*
   Port 22
   User myUser
   ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x gateway.test.io:1080 %h %p

Host sandbox9
   HostName 1.0.9.10

Host sandbox10
   HostName 1.0.10.10

Host sandbox11
   HostName 1.0.11.10
```

I read, that I can use %h in HostName, which would then look like that:

```
Host sandbox*
   Port 22
   User myUser
   ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x gateway.test.io:1080 %h %p
   HostName 1.0.%h.10
```

But then I get the following error when trying to use ssh:

```
❯ ssh sandbox9
nc: connection failed, SOCKS error 8
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

ChatGPT first told me that the first approach should work, but then tells me this:

> The %h placeholder cannot be directly used in the HostName directive of the SSH configuration file to substitute a variable for the hostname. Using placeholders in this specific directive is not supported.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your command, `ssh sandbox9`, tries to connect to `1.0.sandbox9.10`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I only asked ChatGTP because I found many different answers only, also in StackExchange, but nothing worked.

Comment: Reference: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6021/how-do-we-want-to-handle-ai-generated-answers/ and the very comparable discussions regarding questions based on ChatGPT statements over at StackOverflow, Electronics.SE, and several other sites.

Comment: then just ignore ChatGPT: As said, it just forms answer sentences that sound right. And agreeing with you sounds great! No matter how wrong you are.

Comment: the variables you can use are documented. There's an authorative source: when you read `man ssh`, you will be pointed at `man ssh_config` (or you directly go there, because you already know where to look), and it says exactly which placeholders you can use. Same for documentation of `nc`. `man nc` tells us that `-x gateway.test.io:1080` tells `nc` to dump communication as hexdump to a file called "gateway.test.io:1080". Was that what you set out to do?

Comment: (NB: there's various different `nc` out there: the original linuxops one, the nmap one, and the GNU one; on most systems *I* encounter, you get the nmap `netcat` as default `nc`, and that's lead to trouble more than once, hence I'm mentioning it)

Answer (score -1):

Possible that in your OpenSSH client version the `%h` placeholder is not intercepted as the original host, and replaced by `%n` placeholder.

Try the same configuration with `%n` placeholder:

```
Host sandbox*
   Port 22
   User myUser
   ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x gateway.test.io:1080 %n %p
```

You can determine your OpenSSH client version using `ssh -V`

Comment: What do you mean by `%h` being replaced by `%n`? What's the mechanics of that?